# Set Session index in SAML LogoutRequest instance

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am trying to create single logout request using opensaml library through LogoutRequest class. There is no method to set Session index in request object. How do I construct LogoutRequest ?
Code snippet that I am using to construct request object is as below :

```java
SAMLObjectBuilder<LogoutRequest> builder = (SAMLObjectBuilder<LogoutRequest>) builderFactory.getBuilder(LogoutRequest.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);

LogoutRequest request = builder.buildObject();
request.setID(generateID());
request.setVersion(SAMLVersion.VERSION_20);
request.setIssueInstant(new DateTime());
request.setDestination(bindingService.getLocation());

SAMLObjectBuilder<Issuer> issuerBuilder = (SAMLObjectBuilder<Issuer>) builderFactory.getBuilder(Issuer.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
Issuer issuer = issuerBuilder.buildObject();
issuer.setValue(metadata.getHostedSPName());
request.setIssuer(issuer);

SAMLObjectBuilder<NameID> namdIDBuilder = (SAMLObjectBuilder<NameID>) builderFactory.getBuilder(NameID.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
NameID nameid = namdIDBuilder.buildObject();
nameid.setFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient");
request.setNameID(nameid);

SAMLObjectBuilder<SessionIndex> sessionIndexBuilder = (SAMLObjectBuilder<SessionIndex>) builderFactory.getBuilder(SessionIndex.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
SessionIndex sessionindex = sessionIndexBuilder.buildObject();
sessionindex.setSessionIndex(sessionIndex);
```

As you can see above, after building SessionIndex, there is no option to set it in LogoutRequest object.

Can someone show me some example or link to get it right ?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it in the following way:

```java
SessionIndex sessionIndex_ = (SessionIndex) Configuration.getBuilderFactory()
                                            .getBuilder(SessionIndex.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME)
                                            .buildObject(SessionIndex.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);                
sessionIndex_.setSessionIndex("test");
request.getSessionIndexes()
       .add(sessionIndex_);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did in OpenSAML 4.x.

```
SessionIndex sessionIndexElement = OpenSAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(SessionIndex.class);
sessionIndexElement.setValue(samlSessionIndex);
logoutRequest.getSessionIndexes().add(sessionIndexElement);
```

It's been 4 years, but I hope it gets resolved.